# Grails URL mapping optional with double wildcard

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I want to use optional parameter with double wildcard. In Grails 2, I had this pattern and it worked well. In Grails 3, the optional wildcard does not work and `imagePath` is always required, which is not what I want.

`"/image/$action?/$imagePath**?"(controller: "image")`